# How to Switch frame in Selenium java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, test-strategy, debugging

I'm trying to switch frame to email body, but it's not working.

I'm not able to switch frames.

**Expectation:**

I need to `open yopmail` and `get a text` from second email.
Email - Secondemail1234@yopmail.com

```
public Password() {
public static void main(String[] args)          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Browsers\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='ycptinput']")).sendKeys("Secondemail1234"); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']/..//i")).click();
int i = 0 ;
driver.switchTo().frame(i);
WebElement total= driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='lms'])[2]"));
total.click();
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ifmail']")));  //not working to switch to iframe
driver.switchTo().frame(1);  ///not working with index
driver.switchTo().frame("ifmail"); // not working
```

here only I need to switch to frame -- to email body frame I need to switch.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Pls, Accept the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 2):

WebDriver offers three ways of switching to a frame:

**1. Using a WebElement :** find the frame using your preferred selector and switch to it

```
//Store the web element
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#modal>iframe"));

//Switch to the frame
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);

//Now we can click the button
driver.findElement(By.tagName("button")).click();
```

**2. Using a name or ID :** If the name or ID is not unique on the page, then the first one found will be switched to.

```
//Using the ID
driver.switchTo().frame("buttonframe");
//Or using the name instead
driver.switchTo().frame("myframe");
//Now we can click the button
driver.findElement(By.tagName("button")).click();
```

**3. Using an index :** possible to use the index of the frame, such as can be queried using window.frames in JavaScript

```
// Switches to the second frame
driver.switchTo().frame(1);
```

**4. Switch back to the default content:**

```
// Return to the top level
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```